# db record saved in controller and lost in integration spec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

Here is the gems used for our spec in Rails 4.2 engine.

```
  s.add_development_dependency "sqlite3"
  s.add_development_dependency "rspec-rails", ">= 3.2.0"
  s.add_development_dependency "factory_girl_rails", '~>4.5'
  s.add_development_dependency 'capybara'
  s.add_development_dependency 'launchy'
```

Here is a integration spec for create an order record:

```
  visit multi_item_orderx.orders_path(customer_id: @kustomer.id)
  click_link 'New Cob Order'
  expect(page).to have_content('New Order')
  fill_in 'order_order_date', :with => 10.days.ago
  fill_in 'order_order_total', :with => 50
  fill_in 'order_cob_info_bonding_product', :with => 'a bonding prod'
  fill_in 'order_cob_info_name', :with => 'storage'
  fill_in 'order_cob_info_qty', :with => 10
  fill_in 'order_cob_info_unit_price', :with => 10
  click_button 'Save'
  expect(CobOrderx::CobInfo.count).to eq(1)
```

The problem is that `CobOrderx::CobInfo.count returns 0` instead of `1`. In debug,  `@order` is saved successfully and `CobOrderx::CobInfo.count` returns `1`.

But back in spec:

```
expect(CobOrderx::CobInfo.count).to eq(1)
```

returns `false` since `.count` is `0`. We tried to set the following in `rails_helper` and it did not work:

```
config.use_transactional_fixtures = false
```

The problem seems to be with the spec (capybara) and we are not sure why. What could cause the db record lost in integration test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most probable reason in fail to search a created record in `capybara` is that factory girl or direct access to db uses separate connection than capybara, so and data created in one session isn't available in another. To fix it use the [single connection patch](http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2011/12/three-tips-to-improve-the-performance-of-your-test-suite/) (put it to **spec/support**):

```
require 'active_record'

class ActiveRecord::Base
   mattr_accessor :shared_connection
   @@shared_connection = nil

   def self.connection
      @@shared_connection ||= retrieve_connection
   end
end
```

And don't forget to include it into **rails_helper.rb**.

In case if it can't help you, you may try to find an answer in the additional discussions on the topic, which is available [here](http://icloudfaq.com/question/29499/why-not-use-shared-activerecord-connections-for-rspec-+-selenium).

Comment: Interesting!. Do you mean to create a file (any name?) with the code in your post under spec/support (there is no support under our spec subdir)?

Comment: @user938363 yes, and dont forget include it into rails_helper.

Comment: `Dir[File.join(ENGINE_RAILS_ROOT, 'spec/support/**/*.rb')].each {|f| require f }` this is line in `rails_helper`. Is this the right way to include a file under spec/support? A file `single_connection_patch.rb` is created under spec/support. It seems not pickup.